# Latex installation

Tags: miktex, texmaker, installing

Please if any of you know how to install Latex then help me because i did all the steps, including downloading Net installer Miktex in every option and then texmaker all of them for windows 10. But it didn't work for me, i have a problem when i click on the compiler button, the pdf version does not come out to me as it appears in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: You may want to try [Overleaf: on-line LaTeX system](https://www.overleaf.com/)

Answer (score 1):

What Compiler is activated?

Try it with Texstudio if u are completely new. The installer is downloading both.
https://www.texstudio.org/

Comment: Is texstudio like miktex?

Comment: TeXstudio is an integrated writing environment for creating LaTeX documents.
Try it ;) The manual is great. Also you can find good Videos on youtube.